# Paste multi line text from clipboard into Entry control

Tags: maui

I have entry control:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Original}" />
```

Whenever I try to paste the multiline text into it I only get the last line of the text in the control. Is it possible to paste the whole text (e.g. by replacing new line characters with spaces)

Comment: It doesn't make sense for you to fit a multiline text to fit in a single line control, you an Editor...

Comment: There are cases where it is needed (paste multiline text and transform it as single line), hence I'm looking for a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the new line charter with `" "`.

Suppose I want to copy the text of an `Editor` to an `Entry`, then we can do like this:

```
 mEntry.Text = mEditor.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine," ");
```

Comment: This is the easy part but in which event handler will you execute this code? In the `TextChanged` event handler, the subsequent lines after the first line come already cropped (You only get the first line).

Comment: What scenario are you using?

Comment: No matter where you get a multi-line string(e.g. `Clipboard`), you can try to replace the new line charter with " ".

Comment: I copy a 3 lines text from another app and paste it into the `Entry `.

Comment: Using the above method, did not achieve the expected results?

Comment: yeah, `Text.Replace` is the easy part. How do I wire this to the clipboard paste? I want to replace newline characters whenever user pastes the text into the entry control

Comment: Have you tried  [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/clipboard) ?